LWC counterpart for aura's force:outputLookup
I have an old aura component
<aura:component implements="ui:visible,force:hasRecord" description="Makes the record accessible via the Name field as a lookup">
    <force:outputLookup label="{!v.record.Name}" value="{!v.record.Id}"/>
</aura:component>

No helper or controller. I need to create a corresponding LWWC for it, but i cant find any documentation on force:outputLookup
Whats the LWC counterpart for force:outputLookup?
------ further edit after taking sfdcfox inputs -----
I created an LWC customEntityNameLookup. Here are the details -
customEntityNameLookup.js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class CustomEntityNameLookup extends LightningElement {
  @api objectApiName
  @api recordId;
}

customEntityNameLookup.html
<template>
    <lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name={objectApiName}>
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Name">
        </lightning-output-field>       
    </lightning-record-view-form>
</template>

customEntityNameLookup.js-meta.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>61.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

It seems to work fine. When i put it on Order page layout, it displays order name. When i put it on Contract page layout, it displays Contract Name (this is the actual use case for me).
However it shows field label, followed by field value. What i need is just the value (in the name field) which is hyperlinked to the record. If you look at the aura component, it would just display the name, but it's value is record Id, which makes the name hyperlinked.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Maybe we dont need lightning record view form?
Here's another possible code, but i am struggling to get field name dynamically (it could be Order.Name or Contract.Name) -
customEntityNameLookup.js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";

export default class BusopEntityNameLookup extends LightningElement {
  @api objectApiName
  @api recordId;

  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId'})
      object;
  
    get Name() {
        //return the value of the Name field from the record
        return 'HelloWorld';
        //below attempt throws error. I assume because it expects Contract.Name or Order.Name, based on whichever object we are dealing with
        //return getFieldValue(this.object.data, 'Name');
    }

    get RecordURL() {
        //somehow get te URL of the record dynamically
        return 'https://brave-hawk-obcyc7-dev-ed.trailblaze.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Order/801aj00000Oe59dAAB/view';
    }
}

customEntityNameLookup.html
<template>
            <lightning-formatted-url value={RecordURL} label={Name}>
            </lightning-formatted-url>
</template>


There is no analog for this element directly, as you can now use lightning-record-view-form and lightning-output-field:
<lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name={objectName}>
  <lightning-output-field field-name="AccountId">
  </lightning-output-field>
</lightning-record-view-form>


can you please see the update part. Sorry it feels like spoon-feeding, but i moved away from force.com 3 years ago, so i am like brand new to this, and working on a deadline. Any further suggestions would be appreciate.
